# Difference getHeight() vs mBottom - mTop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I just started learning android development (and Java for that matter), and was trying to modify the Sliding Drawer widget. I notice going through the code I find lines like:

```
final int childHeight = mHandleHeight;
int height = mBottom - mTop - childHeight - mTopOffset;
```

Why is "mBottom - mTop" used instead of getHeight()? Also, why is a variable created specifically for childHeight when mHandleHeight already exists?

Code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.java?av=f
line 637

Edit: changed 2nd line in referenced code; those variables (mBottom, mTop) are not available to us when writing our own views, so we have to use the methods 'getTop()' and 'getBottom()' instead.

Comment: I can not say for sure without seeing the entire code, but the line which specifies the height does not just give the height of the widget. It gives the height of the widget MINUS the child height and the top offset. I assume this will give a different value to `getHeight()`.

Comment: I do understand what the height variable is supposed to represent, my question is: is there a difference between 'mBottom - mTop' and 'getHeight()'?  I suspect the writers of this widget would have used the latter option for clarity and brevity if there weren't a difference of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eh, I don't know why I didn't just look at the code for ViewGroup to start with, I'm not used to my SDKs being so open/readily available :)
  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/view/View.java#View.getHeight%28%29 shows the function definition, which is simply

```
6956     public final int getHeight() {
6957         return mBottom - mTop;
6958     }
```

Since this was the primary point of the question, I'll mark as answered once I can and hope someone benefits from this. Still don't know why the extra variable; maybe in multi-threaded environment mChildHeight can change mid-function, so you want a snapshot.